# How to group together data which shares a common property for multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, grouping

I have a problem I am working on solving and am having trouble coming up with a good solution.

I have some data which looks like so:

```
[
  { id: 0, dad: 'Carl', mum: 'Amanda', cat: 'Mittens' },
  { id: 1, dad: 'Ron', mum: 'Amanda', cat: 'Scratch' },
  { id: 2, dad: 'Carl', mum: 'Lucy', cat: 'Tiddles' },
  { id: 3, dad: 'Barry', mum: 'Florence', cat: 'Nyanko' },
  { id: 4, dad: 'Barry', mum: 'Florence', cat: 'Fluffy' },
  { id: 5, dad: 'Carl', mum: 'Stefanie', cat: 'Snuggles' },
...
]
```

**I want to group together entries which share a common dad, mum or cat name**. So I end up with groups such that any member of group 1 doesn't share either a dad, mum or cat's name with any member of any of the other groups. A member of group 1 shares **either** a dad, mum or cat's name with each of the members of it's group.

I have gone about it by grouping them first by each category like so:

```
const groupedByDad = groupBy(data, ({dad}) => dad);
const groupedByMum = groupBy(data, ({mum}) => mum);
const groupedByCat = groupBy(data, ({cat}) => cat);

const groups = [groupedByDad, groupedByMum, groupedByCat]; // array of groups
```

I then extract out just the Ids as I don't need the extra data anymore, just which ids belong in which group.

```
// in next block I extract just the IDs from the original data
groups.forEach((group) => {
  Object.entries(group).forEach(([key, grouping]) => {
    group[key] = grouping.map(({id}) => id);
  });
});
```

I've then come up with a solution where I put all the arrays of Ids in 1 object and iterate through the arrays of ids, for each array I find all arrays of ids which intersect the first and   group them together in a new array and delete them from the array of arrays. I then proceed to the next remaining array and repeat until the original array of arrays is empty. The problem with this is:

- 1: it's slow
- 2: If I have the following arrays of ids in the array of arrays:
  0: [0, 1, 2]
  1: [0, 1, 9]
  2: [9, 8, 4]
  then my algorithm finds that array 1 intersects array 0 and adds it to the matching groups, but finds that array 2 doesn't, as it doesn't intersect array 0. However array 2 DOES intersect array 1 (as they both have id 9 in) and therefore they must share either a cat, dad or mum's name, therefore that group should also be added to the group, but is missed in my implementation. I could repeat the procedure multiple times until no new matches are found, but this seems slow and really inefficient.

There must be a better method/algorithm to group together entries that share at least 1 common property. Could someone advise me on how best to proceed?

I have put the code below to generate some test data and perform the initial grouping:

```
const {groupBy, intersection} = require("lodash");

const dadsNames = ["Barry", "John", "Bill", "Ron", "Carl", "Danny",
  "Dodger", "Filbert", "Charlie", "Frank"];
const mumsNames = ["Lucy", "Mary", "Alice", "Sarah", "Yvonne", "Sandra",
  "Suzie", "Stefanie", "Pearl", "Amanda", "Florence"];
const catsNames = ["Tiddles", "Nyanko", "Paws", "Fluffy", "Scratch", "Snuggles",
  "Impy", "Chris", "Mandrew", "Mittens", "Tuxedo", "Sultan"];

const getRandomEntry = (array) => {
  return array[Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length))];
};

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({id: i, dad: getRandomEntry(dadsNames), mum: getRandomEntry(mumsNames), cat: getRandomEntry(catsNames)});
}

const groupedByDad = groupBy(data, ({dad}) => dad);
const groupedByMum = groupBy(data, ({mum}) => mum);
const groupedByCat = groupBy(data, ({cat}) => cat);

const groups = [groupedByDad, groupedByMum, groupedByCat]; // array of groups

// in next block I extract just the IDs from the original data
groups.forEach((group) => {
  Object.entries(group).forEach(([key, grouping]) => {
    group[key] = grouping.map(({id}) => id);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you need a recursive solution to chase down all the combinations that should fall into a single group, otherwise as noted above in your small sample of 3 ids, subsequent data row entries are not properly included in the group...

Another alternative is to assign bit values to each of the dad, mum, and cat attribute values, then determine the bit mask of the row, and use logical AND to determine the matches that belong to a group.  Of course, once a match is found, the group bit mask is expanded via logical OR and the search continues until no more data rows are found for the group.

Using the example data at the beginning of the question, the bit masks for each attribute value are...

```
0: {"Carl" => 1n}
1: {"Amanda" => 2n}
2: {"Mittens" => 4n}
3: {"Ron" => 8n}
4: {"Scratch" => 16n}
5: {"Lucy" => 32n}
6: {"Tiddles" => 64n}
7: {"Barry" => 128n}
8: {"Florence" => 256n}
9: {"Nyanko" => 512n}
10: {"Fluffy" => 1024n}
11: {"Stefanie" => 2048n}
12: {"Snuggles" => 4096n}
```

...and then these values are used to calculate the data row bit mask values...

```
[
  { id: 0, dad: 'Carl', mum: 'Amanda', cat: 'Mittens' },    ==> 7n
  { id: 1, dad: 'Ron', mum: 'Amanda', cat: 'Scratch' },     ==> 26n
  { id: 2, dad: 'Carl', mum: 'Lucy', cat: 'Tiddles' },      ==> 97n
  { id: 3, dad: 'Barry', mum: 'Florence', cat: 'Nyanko' },  ==> 896n
  { id: 4, dad: 'Barry', mum: 'Florence', cat: 'Fluffy' },  ==> 1408n
  { id: 5, dad: 'Carl', mum: 'Stefanie', cat: 'Snuggles' }  ==> 6145n
]
```

Now, the rows are walked, searching for matches.  First, the group mask is set to the first available row, in this case 7n.  Then, the rows are walked, ANDing the group mask with the row mask.  So, the group mask (7n) is ANDed with the row id 1 mask (26n) resulting in 2n ( "Amanda" ).  Since this indicates a match, row 1 is then added to the group, and the group mask is updated to 7n OR 26n which is 31n, which is a bit mask representing the sum of "Carl", "Amanda", "Mittens", "Ron", and "Scratch".  So now, 31n is the group mask, and 31n ANDed with the row id 2 value (97n) results in 1n, representing "Carl" as the common element.  So, row id 2 is added to the group, and now 31n OR 97n results in 127n as the group mask, which represents the attributes "Carl" through "Tiddles" in the list above.  This continues, rewalking the data rows remaining in the list ( to find related rows that were passed over due to attributes being added to the group later in the search ) until the list is walked and no more data rows are added to the current group.  Then, if there are still data rows remaining, a fresh group is created and the next available data row is used to create the new group, and the cycle of checks repeats...

The implementation ( which randomly creates 10 data rows using the code in the question ) is...

```js
const dadsNames = ["Barry", "John", "Bill", "Ron", "Carl", "Danny", "Dodger", "Filbert", "Charlie", "Frank"];
const mumsNames = ["Lucy", "Mary", "Alice", "Sarah", "Yvonne", "Sandra", "Suzie", "Stefanie", "Pearl", "Amanda", "Florence"];
const catsNames = ["Tiddles", "Nyanko", "Paws", "Fluffy", "Scratch", "Snuggles", "Impy", "Chris", "Mandrew", "Mittens", "Tuxedo", "Sultan"];

const getRandomEntry = (array) => {
  return array[Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length))];
};

var data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  data.push({id: i, dad: getRandomEntry(dadsNames), mum: getRandomEntry(mumsNames), cat: getRandomEntry(catsNames)});
}

function getGroupings( data, attr ) {

  function getAttrMap( data, attr ) {
    let attrMap = new Map();
    let attrMapValue = 1n;
    
    let dataMapValue = new Map();
    let dataIndexList = new Set();

    data.forEach( ( d, i ) => {
      dataIndexList.add( i );
      dataMapValue.set( i, 0n );
      attr.forEach( a => {
        let attrValue = d[ a ];
        if ( !attrMap.has( attrValue ) ) {
          attrMap.set( attrValue, attrMapValue );
          attrMapValue <<= 1n;
        }
        dataMapValue.set( i, dataMapValue.get( i ) + attrMap.get( attrValue ) );
      } );
    } );
    
    console.log( `Binary mapping of attributes:` );
    attrMap.forEach( (v,k) => console.log( `${k}: ${v.toString()}` ) );
    
    console.log( `\nBinary value of each row of data:` );
    dataMapValue.forEach( (v,k) => console.log( `${k}: ${v.toString()}` ) );
    
    return [ dataMapValue, dataIndexList ];
  }

  let groupings = [];
  let [ dataMapValue, dataIndexList ] = getAttrMap( data, ['dad','mum','cat'] );

  while ( dataIndexList.size ) {

    let group = new Set();
    let dataRow = dataIndexList.keys().next().value;
    let mask = dataMapValue.get( dataRow );
    do {
      let entryLength = dataIndexList.size;
      dataIndexList.forEach( k => {
        if ( mask & dataMapValue.get( k ) ) {
          group.add( k );
          dataIndexList.delete( k );
          mask |= dataMapValue.get( k );
        }
      } );
      if ( entryLength === dataIndexList.size ) break;
    
    } while ( true );
    
    groupings.push( group );
    
  }
  
  return groupings;
}

let result = getGroupings( data, ['dad','mum','cat'] );

console.log( `\nData:` );
console.log( data );

console.log( `\nFinal Groupings` );
console.log( result.map( s => [...s] ) );
```

Note that due to the small number of dad, mum, and cat attributes, that as you increase the number of data rows, the higher the likelihood that all the rows will fall into the same group.  Hence, the code above only selects 10 random entries.